# NotificationBar entry is not appearing at defined time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notification-bar

I want to define a time when the notification shall be appear so i followed this tutorial

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

I tested the code in MyAlarmService.onStart and this eams to work, I get the notification.
So it seems the BroadcastReceiver is not work properly.

my code looks like this

MainActivity:

```
/***********************************************************
 * Notification Bar Reminder setup
 **********************************************************/


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

}

MyReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;



public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       context.startService(service1);

    }  
}
```

MyAlarmService:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{

   private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
       /*FR: this code works if you copy it direct to the mainActivity */
       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.whoseturn"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/dummphoto"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyAlarmService"
                 android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calendar.MONTH` is zero-based. That is, `Calendar.JANUARY == 0`. It's better to use the class constants; e.g. `Calendar.DECEMBER`. Also, `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` is based in the 24-hour clock.

I would also point out that you're setting the alarm with `AlarmManager.RTC`, which will not wake-up your device to fire it. If that behavior is what you need, use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` instead.

A couple of notes for testing:

- `Calendar.getInstance()` returns an instance with the current date and time already set. You need only set those components that differ from right now.
- If an alarm is set at or before the current time, it will fire immediately. This is a good test to make sure the Receiver is setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and good answer. The MONTH was indeed the issue. Do you know if it is possible to extend the code easily to an weekly or daily Notification?

Comment: Sure. If your scheduling is relatively simple, you just need to use one of the repeating `set*()` methods. [The docs for `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) do a decent job of explaining everything. You might pay careful attention to the differences between the exact and inexact methods. Depending on your requirements, and the Android version you're on, you might have to account for those things.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that if your Service isn't going to be doing a lot of work, an `IntentService` might be more appropriate, and they're generally easier to implement.